# "Error: The function applied to this argument has type ..." when using named parameters

Tags: ocaml, named-parameters, utop

I'm currently working through "Real Word OCaml", and one of the basic examples with named / labeled parameters doesn't seem to work (using utop 4.01.0):

```
let languages = ["OCaml"; "Perl"; "C"];;
List.map ~f:String.length languages;;
```

Produces:

```
Error: The function applied to this argument has type 'a list -> 'b list
This argument cannot be applied with label ~f
```

Whereas:

```
List.map String.length languages;;
```

Produces the expected output `[5; 4; 1]`.

[caml.inria.fr](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/ocaml051.html) mentions that:

> In the core language, as in most languages, arguments are anonymous.

Does this mean that I have to include some kind of external library to make this code work ?

**EDIT**
Here's my `~/.ocamlinit` file (as per the [installation instructions for the book](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions)):

```
(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =                
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;

#use "topfind"
#camlp4o
#thread
#require "core.top"
#require "core.syntax"
```

Comment: I would expect the library needed to make this example work is Core (an “Industrial strength alternative to OCaml's standard library” as listed on https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/ ). Does the book not mention something about installing it first?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I've installed Core correctly; see my updated answer.

Comment: Did you put 'open Core.Std ;;' first ?

Comment: @rafix That did the trick. If you add this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in @rafix's comment, this can be fixed by putting

```
open Core.Std ;;
```

first.

Comment: In newer versions, `Core.Std` is depracated. Use `open Core;;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The standard List.map method isn't defined with the label ~f. The type of List.map is ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list, but if you wanted to use the "~f" label, it would have to be "f:('a->'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list". If you wanted to define your own, you would have to define it as such:

```
 let rec myMap ~f l = match l with
 | [] -> []
 | h::t -> (f h) :: (myMap ~f t);;

 val myMap : f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

and then you could call it like you wanted:

```
 myMap ~f:String.length languages
```

Cheers!

Comment: +1 I don't want to define my own map function, but knowing how to use labeled parameters is certainly useful :-)

Comment: There is no lambda? why must use a label ?